# Docker registry: Can't find image

Tags: docker, http-status-code-404, docker-registry

I try to pull my Docker Image:

```
Trying to pull repository myrepo:5000/ubuntu ... not found                 
Error: image ubuntu:latest not found
```

The image is in my repo:

```
root@e65daf20372e:/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories# ls
busybox  ubuntu
```

The logs are showing:

```
10.0.0.xx - - [17/Dec/2015:10:18:55 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "" "docker/1.8.2 go/go1.4.2 kernel/3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64"
10.0.0.xx - - [17/Dec/2015:10:18:55 +0000] "GET /v1/repositories/ubuntu/images HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "docker/1.8.2 go/go1.4.2 kernel/3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64"
```

So I got a `404`-error while searching for the image but it's searching in `/v1` while the path to the image describes `/v2`

Is this the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does the "ubuntu" image you pushed to the registry have a "latest" tag?

Comment: (you can check easily by hitting http://myrepo:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list)

Answer (score 1):

Is your private repository password protected?   I have seen error 404 on a known good tag when the real problem is that the user has not authenticated, i.e. 'docker login https://myrepo:5000'